# Finding unique values of one column for specific column values

Tags: python, pandas

given the following df:

```
data = {'identifier': {0: 'a',
  1: 'a',
  3: 'b',
  4: 'b',
  5: 'c'},
 'gt_50': {0: 1, 1: 1, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0},
 'gt_10': {0: 1, 1: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1}}
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

i want to find the nuniques of the column "identifier" for each column that starts with "gt_" and where the value is one.

Expected output:

```
- gt_50 1
- gt_10 3
```

I could make a for loop and filter the frame in each loop on one gt column and then count the uniques but I think it's not very clean.
Is there a way to do this in a clean way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with filter `_gt` columns for unpivot, then get rows with `1` in [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) and last count unique values by [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html):

```
out = (df.melt('identifier', value_vars=df.filter(regex='^gt_').columns)
         .query('value == 1')
         .groupby('variable')['identifier']
         .nunique())
print (out)
variable
gt_10    3
gt_50    1
Name: identifier, dtype: int64
```

Or:

```
s = df.set_index('identifier').filter(regex='^gt_').stack()
out = s[s.eq(1)].reset_index().groupby('level_1')['identifier'].nunique()
print (df)
level_1
gt_10    3
gt_50    1
Name: identifier, dtype: int64
```